# Secondary x and y axes when merging 2 chart types in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I've been trying to merge two types of charts (column & line) into a single one. I've managed to do so, but I couldn't get de desired format, that is having 2 y axes, one bottom x axis and a top x axis. 
With MS Excel 2010 it's possible to achieve this look but I didn't mange to get the same result with my python code.

Here my python code:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10],
    [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
    [200,200,100,100,300,300,250,250,350,350]
]
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])
worksheet.write_column('D2', data[3])
#
chart_1= workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
#
chart_1.add_series ({                                                           
    'name': 'Data',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6',
    'fill': {'color': '#004d96'},
    'gap': 5,
    'y2_axis': True
})    
#
chart_2= workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
#
chart_2.add_series ({                                                           
    'name': 'Data 2',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$2:$D$11',
    'line': {'color': '#ff0000'},
    'x2_axis': True
})
chart_2.combine(chart_1)

chart_1.set_x_axis({                                                                                                                 
    'name': 'Step',
    'interval_unit': 1,
    'interval_tick': 1,
    'major_tick_mark': 'none',
    })
#
chart_1.set_y2_axis({                                                            
    'name': 'Value',
    })
chart_2.set_x2_axis({                                                                                                                   
    'name': 'Step',
    'interval_unit': 1,
    'interval_tick': 1,
    'visible': True
    })
#
chart_2.set_y_axis({                                                            
    'name': 'Value',
    })    
worksheet.insert_chart('B20', chart_2)
workbook.close()
```

This leads me to the following result:
[Current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIGPK.jpg)

What I would like to obtain though should look like this:
[Alternative to the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg3ul.jpg)

Or even better like this:
[Ideal Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrNSW.jpg)

Comment: Options 2 and 3 aren't currently possible with XlsxWriter.

Comment: Hello, @jmcnamara and thank you for your reply! 
I've been asking myself, if I should also post this question on github but since you've replied, I won't be needing it anymore. 
Is there going to be any new version of xlsxwriter that will support a secondary x-axis?
Could you please then explain the "set_x2_axis()" command? What purpose does it have? I've tried to work with this command but didn't get any results.
And most importantly: is there any way to create option 3 or 2 with other modules?

Comment: You can use `set_x2_axis()`. You just can't use it when you are also using `set_y2_axis()`. This may be fixed/added in the future, however, it is quite a bit of work and there haven't been many (or any) requests for it so it is unlikely to be added in the short term.

Comment: Hey @jmcnamara. Ok, thanks for your explication. Yeah, I thought so myself when I started researching about this because I couldn't find any discussions on this subject. Nevertheless it would be a nice option to have.